# Spring Data JPA's findById cannot be invoke; nullPointerException

Tags: spring, jpa, spring-data-jpa, spring-test

Im checking for the case when searched for an id which is not present in the database returns null.

But the test case keeps on interrupting with nullPointerException;
It is supposed to be returning null and i guess it is doing that, but for some reason my test case is not passing it.

Test Case

```
@Test
    public void testFindWrongComplaintDetailsById() {
        long id = 2;

        when(emergencyComplaintRepository.findById(id)).thenReturn(null);
        assertNull(emergencyComplaintService.findComplaintDetailsById(id));
    }
```

Service

```
@Override
    public EmergencyComplaint findComplaintDetailsById(long id) {
        return emergencyComplaintDAO.findById(id);
    }
```

DAO

```
@Override
    public EmergencyComplaint findById(long id) {
        return emergencyComplaintRepository.findById(id).orElse(null);
    }
```

Error
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to return the `Optional.empty()` for `emergencyComplaintRepository.findById(id)` as shown below.

```
@Test
    public void testFindWrongComplaintDetailsById() {
        long id = 2;

        when(emergencyComplaintRepository.findById(id)).thenReturn(Optional.empty());
        assertNull(emergencyComplaintService.findComplaintDetailsById(id));
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

That's because you should return an `Optional<EmergencyComplaint>` from your repository's method, that's what `orElse` is expecting.

By the way, using this method to return `null` is a complete misuse. If you want to return `null`, the use of `orElse` is unnecessary, a bad practice, and it's causing you this trouble on top of everything.